# Local Light OpenGL

Tags: java, c++, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I was working with some OpenGL, and can't quite seem to get some code to work correctly. I know how to adjust the ambient light of a scene using OpenGL, but I can't seem to get a local light, like how a match only lights up the direct area around it, or a spotlight to work. This is my lighting code, which only contains an ambient and spotlight:

```
private float[] lightPosition0;
public  float[] light_ambient0 = {0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f}; 
private float[] light_diffuse0 = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
private float[] light_specular0 = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

private float[] light_ambient1 = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
private float[] light_specular1 = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
private float[] light_specref1 = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
private float[] light_spot_direction = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

@SubscribeEvent()
public void onWorldRender(RenderWorldEvent.Pre event)
{
   render();
}

private void render() 
{
   //glPushMatrix();

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

   lightPosition0 = new float[]{(float)thePlayer.getPlayerCoordinates().posX + 2, (float)thePlayer.getPlayerCoordinates().posY + 2, (float)thePlayer.getPlayerCoordinates().posZ + 2, 1.0f}; // not sure what the last value does

  // LIGHT 0
  glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(lightPosition0));
  glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(light_ambient0));
  glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(light_diffuse0));
  glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(light_specular0));

  // Light 1
  glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(light_ambient1));
  glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(light_specular1));
  glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(lightPosition0));
  glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 60.0f);
  glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 100.0f);

  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
   glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);

//glPopMatrix();
}
```

I'm trying to get a spotlight to point down a few units ahead of the player. Also, I don't know if I should be using GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER or GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, or why my code isn't working. I'm not attached to using a fixed pipeline and not using shaders, if it's easier to do that way I'd gladly do it that way.

I'm not sure how I'd even go about doing an emissive light that doesn't go on infinitely. I'm sure there's a GL method for it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The world I'm rendering these lights in is made up of same-sized cubes, if that is important information.